External drives causing root partition to be reported "full"
I had this recurring problem on my previous PC and thought I was being smart but I wasn't: my 2 external 2 tB HDD backup drives, to which I backup nightly (to protect myself from previous disasters) keep on causing / to be reported as 100% full and unmounting these drives does not change that. How can I stop this occurring (without stopping my backups from running). It seems that adding backup drives does not solve this.
Here is my primary drive (an NVMe SSD) df -k output:
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            1568036      2516   1565520   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1 383373848 383307144         0 100% /
tmpfs            7840168    121532   7718636   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
efivarfs             256        64       188  26% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p4    192559      6186    186374   4% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p2 960491528 180754856 730872672  20% /home
tmpfs            1568032       176   1567856   1% /run/user/1000

If I can shrink /home and add it to / it seems to me this will fill up in a jiffy, based on past experience.

My system is installed on a 96GB partition; yet if I explore df output and add up values it'll add up to >20TB due to my mounts. Additional mounts use NO SPACE on / so your logic is faulty, and you're missing something (and that's also why unmounting doesn't gain you space; as none was used!).  You've provided no release details, but your space problem is something different what what you're currently blaming.

I have had my backup partition not be mounted, and then it copied my backup into / filing it. check /. I also have links and had data copied into a folder but then somehow uses link to same place. Data was hidden under link & I could only see it when using live installer. I like ncdu to review data use. You may need to install it.

I'm sorry but I disagree. The proof of the pudding is in the eating: I cannot boot the system as even Boot_repair says / is full, yet all that space being consumed is in /media//>external USB drive>. I have had hours of work trying to find a workaround. In the end I removed some files from one of those external drives mounted on /media and was able to reboot. What does that tell you? I am still perplexed as to why, even when I have unmounted those drives, Ubuntu still thinks / is full.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 on a brand new HP Victus 15L with Ryzen 5 5600g and, as you can see, a 2 tB NVMe SSD, which is the sole internal storage device  - I yanked the 500 Gb SSD containing Windows 11 and replaced it with the 2 tB on which I installed Ubuntu. I thought I was smart partitioning the drive with lots of space on /home but, in the space of 3 weeks / was filled up because of the backups to the external HDDs.

Since I had no suggestions on how to fix this problem I had a go at asking ChatGPT what to do. It suggested removing all those external drive mount points from /media and mounting them on /mnt/. I am in the process of doing this and adding those new mount points ro /etc/fstab. I have so far found no adverse problems apart from not being able to reboot until I fixed fstab problems. I'm using "mount -a" to test the mounts going forward.

I have moved all the external drives to /mnt and so far so good. I have some errors in the primary partitions of 2 of the 3 externals - the ntfs checks say they are dirty. That's no big deal for me now. I have yet to summon the courage to delete the /media subdirectories where the external HDDs previously were mounted. No hurry to do that.

Everything still OK but here is something slightly baffling to me: The HP Victus 15L desktop comes with only an NVMe SSD but there is a place to mount a hard drive and there are SATA data and power cables in the case. I connected them to a 1tB WD HDD with Ubuntu on it but the system boots only into emergency mode, unless I force it via BIOS to boot the HDD or use a basic /etc/fstab which has no entries other than the NVMe. This is not important. I just thought I could provide a 2nd or 3rd level of safety.

With my heart in my mouth I deleted all subdirectories of /media/ and suddenly the disk usage in / dropped from 86% to 4%! As I said earlier the proof of the pudding is in the eating and I've learned a valuable lesson that could have saved me from getting this new PC.
